# Tracking pages without analytics code

Tags: google, google-analytics, tracking

Do you have an idea how Google can track pages on the server without analytics code? The  folder is prohibited by `robots.txt` too!

I can see the URL of those pages on the real time counter.

Comment: robots.txt affects how Googlebot will crawl your site, not how Google Analytics will work. Are you totally sure you don't have tracking code in there somewhere?

Comment: Can you post a link to the folder?

Answer (score 1):

If your Google Analytics account is still giving your new data you have the code stuck somewhere still on your website. Render your website and view the source and search foryour Analytics ID. Also, Robots.txt won't matter if you've blocked the spiders. If you've got the code snippet on your website it will still be tracking no matter what.

Comment: No doubts that's for sure now ,I have a folder with my admin files no reason to track them ,it is tracked too by google is it made with cookies?